# Javascript - What are the performance differences between an array with keys and an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory

I'm in an assignment right now for my bootcamp, and I'm playing around with looping through objects.

For what I'm doing, it's prudent to have an object of other objects. The only issue is looping through it (which I could do with something like Object.keys()).

But I'm wondering what the difference is between an array with keys and an object with keys? I'm used to languages where only objects/dictionaries have keys, and it's a little odd for me to have an array that can have keys.

Are there any performance differences here? For instance, are arrays always stored adjacent to each other in memory while Objects aren't and therefore don't allow certain functions arrays have?

Comment: Typically you don't add keyed properties to arrays in JS. Use the indexed properties of arrays only, i.e. number indices. The answer to question is, no difference, both are similar objects. Using indexed properties of an array would be faster, and you can rely on the order of the indices.

Comment: As soon as you start discussing memory layout, none of that is covered by the ECMAScript specification. Either pick a target implementation to discuss like V8, or accept the answer "that's an implementation detail"

Comment: arrays are heavily optimized for typical array operations, on most engines. It's a gigantic topic, and i don't think would possibly fit into an answer here. To give a hint (the article is from 2012, and probably outdated), you can look at [this post](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/), it will give you an idea of how complex the topic is.

Comment: You must not worries at all with that, go with what you are comfortable with. For high loads of computations, indexed iterables array of integers is the fastest by a little, it apply in all programming langs.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. I am somewhat well versed in performance issues in other languages. I know about certain data structures and time complexities and what operations are going to work in what data structures. But I should clarify that an indexed array is not possible in the situation we are in. It's necessary to be able to pull a specific name out of a list, and it's also necessary to loop through that list. In that context, it sounds like it doesn't matter as much if it's an array with keys or an object. Am I understanding that correctly? I would assume the latest ES standard

Comment: This is interesting. For performances avoid loops for searching. Try to create unique hashes, store by hash in an object. Then to `pull a specific name out of a list`, read the index by hash directly: `... = obj[hash]` this has many advantages. If that can help see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2494754+sha

Comment: Maybe a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?